# Is it possible to change the appearance of a Rave report's Preview form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, rave-reports

When users preview a report I would like to avoid giving them the option of then opening another report or saving the current report. Open and Save are items in the default menu and toolbar that appear on Rave's preview rendering form; I'd like to make them not visible.

I'm using the version of Rave that comes with Delphi 2006.

Thanks, as always -- Al C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Rave System object then it is easy to disable the Save menu option by setting this property to false:

System Properties->SystemOptions->soAllowSaveFromPreview

If you are not using a Rave System object, it is easy to add one.  Then set the Rave Project Engine property to the new System object.  You shouldn't need to change any code.  The Rave project will then use the properties in the System object when generating reports.

I believe I tried to figure out how to disable the File-Open menu but I didn't have any luck.  Once users can no longer save reports, there won't be any Rave reports for them to open unless your application is saving report files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I look forward to trying it out when I'm in front of my source code ... I'm with you on the File-Open point. Thanks for trying to figure it out. I was trying to prevent users from trying to open non-Rave report files, too.